outline in pdf bookmarks points to some other section
The outline in pdf bookmarks points to some other section after redefining sectioning commands. Upon clicking Methodology in the pdf bookmark points me to the Introduction section. I wonder if it can be corrected somehow. Here is the code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
This is the introduction section. \lipsum[2-4]


\subsection{Background}
This is the background subsection. \lipsum[2-4]


\subsubsection{Details}
This is the details subsubsection. \lipsum[2-4]


% Redefine sectioning commands here
\renewcommand{\thesection}{S\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{S\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{S\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\section{Methodology}
This is the methodology section. \lipsum[2-4]


\subsection{Approach}
This is the approach subsection. \lipsum[2-4]


\subsubsection{Implementation}
This is the implementation subsubsection. \lipsum[2-4]


\end{document}


You need to also update \theHsection (what is used by Hyperref).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
This is the introduction section. \lipsum[2-4]

\subsection{Background}
This is the background subsection. \lipsum[2-4]

\subsubsection{Details}
This is the details subsubsection. \lipsum[2-4]


% Redefine sectioning commands here
\renewcommand{\thesection}{S\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\theHsection}{S\arabic{section}}% Also works: \renewcommand{\theHsection}{\thesection}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\section{Methodology}
This is the methodology section. \lipsum[2-4]

\subsection{Approach}
This is the approach subsection. \lipsum[2-4]

\subsubsection{Implementation}
This is the implementation subsubsection. \lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}

Note the recursive (re)definition of \thesubsection and \thesubsubsection in terms of the higher sectioning numbering.

thanks so much. this answers my question.
